# Adding classes to <a>

Tags: theming, 8

I am trying to add classes to the `<a>` tag output from menu.html.twig. I can add these classes to the `<li>`, but not the `<a>` tag.

In the twig file I have a loop and I need to add the classes 'link-1', 'link-2' etc to each `<a>` tag:

```
{% for item in items %}
  <li{{ item.attributes.addClass('link-'~loop.index) }}>
    {{ link(item.title, item.url)}}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

This outputs the class on the `<li>`:

```
<li class="link-1">
```

How do I set the code below on the `<a>` tag instead?

```
item.attributes.addClass('link-'~loop.index)
```

So the result I am looking for will be:

```
<li><a class="link-1">Link Text</a></li>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try code below:

```
{% for item in items %}
  <li>
    {%
      set attributes = attributes.setAttribute('class', 'link-'~loop.index)
    %}
    {{ link(item.title, item.url, attributes)}}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

more detail about [attributes in twig](https://www.drupal.org/node/2513632) and [link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Template%21TwigExtension.php/function/TwigExtension%3A%3AgetLink/8)