# Inserting Font Awesome HTML into user profile fields with Twig

Tags: 8, theming

I have created user profile fields for Twitter, LinkedIn and GitHub that are just plain Link Fields.

I would like to add the relevant Font Awesome icon HTML to each of the fields so that the icon is printed instead of the URL. I would like this to happen in all instances of the field being used whether its a view or the user entity.

What preprocess function should I use? How should I add the HTML to the template using Twig?

Comment: Create new Field Formatter based off of the \Drupal\link\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter\LinkFormatter

Comment: This is also similar to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/187234/adding-classes-to-a